# AspectJ, Can it be used for large scale loggin

Tags: logging, aspectj, scribe

I am adding logging into existing source code (large source code) to give a detailed logging, we decided the backend for logging (using face book scribe, and tested ). I am thinking of using Aspect oriented ways to add logging calls into all the functions (to start with)

Is this a good approach to use AspectJ to handle log collection, will it have any impact on the performance of the system.

Mani

Answer (score 4):

Performance overhead added by AspectJ itself will be negligible (assuming you will use build-time weaving). Obviously, the logging will have its own performance impact that will depend on how wide (number of join points) and deep (information logged) is your logging.

In other words, performance difference between logging added through AspectJ and equivalent manually implemented code will be negligible.